# codeship: How to disable test command?

Tags: meteor, codeship

I am doing meteor app and using codeship for the auto build to Digitalocean with `mupx` package.I want to deploy only master branch to digitalocean. `Deployment` commands are running at the master branch, It works fine. But `test` command works at every pushes to the other branches. How to disable `test` command at every push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's currently not possible. See [Limit Builds to Specific Branches](https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/limit_builds/) for the reasoning.

Main reason is that running your tests early and often is important to get good feedback and build trust into your test suite. Limiting builds to specific branches that get only triggered every couple days (or even less) would not do that.

See [Skipping Builds](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-integration/skipping-builds/) for how to skip individual builds.

(Also posted on our [Community Forum](https://community.codeship.com/t/how-to-disable-test-command/638))